# Dummit and Foote 14.4.6

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I'm having a problem solving this problem from dummit & foote.

prove that 
$F_p(x,y)/F_p(x^p,y^p)$ is not a simple extension n by explicitly exhibiting
an infinite number of intermediate sub-fields

Honestly i have no idea where to start.

Comment: I hope your $F_p$ denotes the finite field on $p$ elements, isnt it?

Comment: Here are some intermediate fields: $\Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p,x)$, $\Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p,y)$, $\Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p,xy)$. Can you show that these are indeed intermediate, and are pairwise different? Can you guess a pattern to find infinitely many such fields?,

Comment: @vidyarthi yes of course

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but wouldn't it stop at $x^p$ or $ y^p$? and hence not infinite?

Comment: @MosheLevy I think you could keep extending the pattern, for example, by setting the next field $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p,x^py,xy^p)\ldots\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p,x^ny^n)$ for $n$ approaching to infinty (a multiple of $p$)?

Comment: @vidyarthi you are probably right but why are they different? could i get a hint on how to show that they are not equal?

Comment: @MosheLevy the field $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p,x^py)$ for instance consists of all the linear combinations of the elements inside the brackets, which would not have, for example the term $xy^p$, which would be present in $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p,xy^p)$

Comment: @vidyarthi thank you

Comment: I seem to have handled this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1824104/11619). Thankfully I don't have a dupehammer here, so I can vote to close as a duplicate freely. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445525/11619) for a more thorough discussion by people who know more than I do.